# heroku for node: ! Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express

I am new to heroku and express.js. I try to go through the tutorial, but I cannot make it with the step 'git push heroku master'. I followed the tutorial exactly. Below is the error message:

```
Counting objects: 269, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (241/241), done.
Writing objects: 100% (269/269), 188.93 KiB, done.
Total 269 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:cryptic-journey-9914.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:cryptic-journey-9914.git'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

did you read the [Getting Started with Node.js on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs) article on Heroku Dev Center?

You need to [declare your process type with Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs#declare-process-types-with-procfile). To do so, create a file named `Procfile`, with the following content:

```
web: node web.js
```

assume that your javascript file is called `web.js`.

p.s. don't forget to add the Procfile to git and commit it.

Comment: It might be package.json, I set to ignore json files in git. I force git to add it and now it works, thanks!

Comment: You might also want to check this [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore) file from github.

Comment: As they talk about a text file on heroku docs I'd like to add that it is called Procfile and not Procfile.txt.      @howanghk you say it right "create a file named Procfile", in the docs they just say "Use a Procfile, a text file in the root directory of your application,..."    .  their docs suck, where shall I know that the file is called Procfile. They should pay you money for making their documentation :)

Answer (score 7):

You need a package.json file (and a Procfile), it is likely not the case.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this issue a few time before and it was because I was trying to push a remote branch to heroku.

To solve the problem, instead of using:

```
git push heroku master
```

I used:

```
git push heroku my-branch:master
```

This pushes the remote branch `my-branch` in the git repository to the `master` branch of heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I had the same problem and it turned out to be one of the Config Vars in Heroku.
I remove the config vars and the app was pushed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For me, doing `npm init` was enough