# how to make a page online with some .js files using any free hosting service

Tags: web, web-hosting

I created a webpage with the help of angular js which will display news feeds from multiple sources. I need to host it for free. But i learned that google blogger or free online web hosting sites doesnt allow to upload js files other than pictures.

So I want to know is there any means to host that page easily and free.

Comment: It's possible to add Javascript to a Blogger site. You need to add the Javascript inside an HTML <script> tag in the HTML editor.

Answer (score 2):

Upload your webpage to www.000webhost.com . It allows to host nearly everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.000webhost.com/ It has many services like PHP, MySQL etc. Use FileZilla for uploading the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use heroku to deploy it as a simple node js application.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

Check out [How do I deploy an Angular.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674202/how-do-i-deploy-an-angular-js-app)